# On math and what not?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

In an email a friend of mine wrote to me:

> I got a couple of books from a friend on math  and *what not*.

Can anyone please tell me what does ***what not*** mean here? If there is any meaning.

Comment: I disagree with the close voter. You could look up both _what_ and _not_ in a dictionary and sift through the meanings for a very long time and still be puzzled. Only after you realize "whatnot" has its own entry does the problem become trivial – but clearly the O.P. didn't have that clue to the puzzle. This is a fair ELL question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like your friend has inserted a space in *whatnot*, as you have done in *anyone*.

From [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/and-or-whatnot):

> People sometimes say 'and whatnot' or 'or whatnot' after mentioning one or more things, to refer in a vague way to other things which are similar. (*informal, spoken, vagueness*)   ⇒ *"The women were there in their jeans and T-shirts and overalls and whatnot."   ⇒ "The council can send messages or letters or whatnot in Spanish."*

Comment: Thank you very much ! yes you have found my and my friends problem. I have fixed mine, hopefully he is going to fix his next time. I googled it and understood it even more :)